# Is This Logic About Node.JS - Router True?

Tags: node.js, express

i'm new in node.js. i made routes/index like this and i don't know is it good or not? 
my code worked perfectly but : 
1 - can anyone explain is this code standard? 
2 - can i use external folder/file for my controller ? like : 
 controller/users/index.js 
controller/api/index.js

routes/index.js

```
var express = require("express")
var router = express.Router()
var request = require("request");


let index = {

    // ## Controls
    getBTC: function () {
        request.get("http://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json", (err, response, body) => {
            if (err) {
                return console.dir(err);
            }
            rate = JSON.parse(body).bpi.USD.rate
            time = JSON.parse(body).time.updated
        })
    },

    // ## Routes
    indexRoute: function () {
        router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
            res.render('common/index', {
                title: 'Index Title',
                rate: this.rate,
                time: this.time
            })
        })
    },

    testRoute: function () {
        router.get('/test', function (req, res, next) {
            res.render('common/test', {
                title: 'Test Title',
                rate: this.rate
            })
        })
    }

}

index.getBTC() //-> Enable For All Routes
index.indexRoute()
index.testRoute()

module.exports = router
```

views/common/index.pug

```
extends ../layout

block content
    p #{rate}
    h1 #{time}
```

Comment: This question may get better responses on [codereview.stackexchange.com](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: thanks i didn't know that site